# Android:Image not found inside drawable folder Exception handling

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get image from drawable folder using a string in words. And Iwant to  check for an exception in which the image is not found inside the drawable folder.But the code below show and error saying:**Unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException.This exception is never thrown from the try statement body**.Is there any exception type that handles this kind of error?

```
              try
            {
       imid = getResources().getIdentifier(words[i], "drawable", getPackageName());
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
           {
              //Sorry. image not found. 

           }
```

Anybody with a suggestion. Thank u in advance.

Comment: I tink the getResources() returns null if it can't find the resource. You could check if the var is null instead of catching an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `FileNotFoundException` with `Exception` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether it this null:

```
if(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.andro_icon)!= null)
{
    // Do your things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) function doesn't throw any exception, how you can see in documentation it returns 0 if resource was not found. So you must compare imid with 0(and can remove try catch):

```
if(imid == 0)
{
  ...hanlde file not found exception...
}
```